# Raise the CPU temperature

Tags: performance, cpu, temperature, busybox

**Problem:** I want to maximize the CPU usage and eventually raise the operating temperature of my CPU. My ultimate goal is to see if I can reach thermal runaway on my Linux device. This is not a full PC, it’s just a display running some light applications.

- No I cannot run multiple applications at a time, it is designed to run a single application at a time.
- I can connect to the device only through SSH. There is no GUI interface.

**Question:** Is there a way I can reach thermal runaway using a script?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Have you tried a calculation-heavy application such as a Mandelbrot fractal generator? For example Fraqtive in the Ubuntu software center?

Comment: @Joe I will try this, this didn't cross my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility called '[stress](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=stress)' you could use.